# Problem using metro webservice stack with JBoss

Tags: jboss, java-metro-framework

I am using Metro 2.1 together with JBoss 4.2.2.

The application deploys without errors but when I try to access a WebService I get the following error:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not found (see full stack trace below)
```

The Problem is that Jboss tries to load the `ProviderImpl` of it's own webservice implementation instead it should use the `ProviderImpl` from the metro implementation.

In `META-INF/services/javaw.xml.ws.spi.Provider` I have configured: `com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl`.

Why does Jboss not use the metro stack?

Ingo

Full stack trace:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:214)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$400(ServiceLoader.java:164)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:350)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:421)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Provider.java:146)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:106)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.trust.impl.TrustPluginImpl.invokeRST(TrustPluginImpl.java:547)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.trust.impl.TrustPluginImpl.process(TrustPluginImpl.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.trust.impl.client.STSIssuedTokenProviderImpl.getIssuedTokenContext(STSIssuedTokenProviderImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.trust.impl.client.STSIssuedTokenProviderImpl.issue(STSIssuedTokenProviderImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.security.trust.client.IssuedTokenManager.getIssuedToken(IssuedTokenManager.java:83)
    at com.cg.ihe.doc.impl.GespagTokenGenerator.createToken(GespagTokenGenerator.java:108)
    at com.cg.ihe.doc.sourceadapter.impl.TianiIheAuthenticationProvider.login(TianiIheAuthenticationProvider.java:100)
    at com.cg.ihe.doc.impl.ConfigurableDocumentProvider.createSession(ConfigurableDocumentProvider.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:160)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:54)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:160)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy99.createSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.cg.ihe.doc.impl.DexaMinerServiceImpl.createSession(DexaMinerServiceImpl.java:
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this and it worked for jboss 4.2.3 and metro 3.1.1:

from http://community.jboss.org/thread/1080 :

> I was able to overcome the problem by removing the jboss-jaxws.jar from the JBOSS_HOME/server/name/lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
META-INF/services/javaw.xml.ws.spi.Provider
```

to

```
META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
```

(note javax)